# Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect) Unable to connect MSSQL using PyODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server using Pypyodbc on Mac and I'm getting the following error:

```
Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

Below is my code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};DSN=MYMSSQL;UID=<>;PWD=<>')
crsr = conn.cursor()
rows = crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM transaction_detail_check").fetchall()
print(rows)
crsr.close()
conn.close()
```

odbcinst.ini
[image]

odbc.ini

[image]

freetds.conf

[image]

Can someone please help ?  Thanks

Comment: If your DSN specifies the driver then you don't need both `DRIVER=` and `DSN=` in your pyodbc connection string; just the `DSN=` should be sufficient.

Comment: When I remove Driver, I get the following error:    Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Try running `odbcinst -j` to verify that the odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini files are located where UnixODBC expects them to be.

Comment: I did try that, the location is correct. FYI I am using a Mac. Thanks for your pointers, is there anything else that you may suggest ?

Comment: A few other guesses: Make sure that there are no blank lines or whitespace at the beginning of the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files, and check that they are saved as plain "ANSI" text, not Unicode (to avoid the possibility of a byte order mark (BOM) or invisible Unicode characters confusing things).

Comment: Your Setup value in odbcinst.ini seems to be wrong: It should point to something like `/usr/local/lib/libtdsS.so`.